# Библиотеки для изменения тембра голоса

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Встала задача программно менять тембр и скорость голоса.
Знаю что для этого есть виндовые приложения , но библиотек под Python найти пока не удалось.
Возможно кто то может поделиться названиями либ с нужным функционалом?

Comment: Скорее ffmpeg или SoX больше подойдут, в них совершенная прорва возможностей

Answer (score 1):

**Кроссплатформенно:**

```
pip3 install pyttsx3
```

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Hello world')
engine.runAndWait()
```

> Или просто: `pyttsx3.speak("Hello world")`, [исходники](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blob/021a97bea88fee471fc179b4119fe5cc06566185/pyttsx3/__init__.py#L27].). В [readme](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3) можно найти как поменять громкость, частоту и т.п.

**Mac OS X:**

```
import os
os.system('say "hello world"')
```

**Требует интернета:**

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
tts = gTTS(text='Hello world', lang='en')
tts.save("good.mp3")
os.system("mpg321 good.mp3")
```

**iOS Pythonista:**

```
import speech
speech.say('Hola mundo', 'es_ES')
```

**Mac OS/Linux espeak**:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install espeak
#linux
```

```
brew install espeak#mac os
```

```
import os
os.system('espeak "This is a test"')
```

---

[Вот еще статья](https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-text-to-speech-with-python-bfb34250036e)

Comment: Или просто: `pyttsx3.speak("Hello world")`, исходники: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blob/021a97bea88fee471fc179b4119fe5cc06566185/pyttsx3/__init__.py#L27 . В readme можно найти как поменять громкость, частоту и т.п.: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3 . Странно, но в репозитории есть `def speak(text):`, а тот, что я установил -- нет. Возможно, это новая вещь и ее не выгрузили в pypi

Comment: не совсем то ,что мне нужно. У меня уже есть аудиодорожка с голосом.
понятно что TextToSpeech умеет делать разные тембры. 
А вот чтобы изменить уже готовый ,записанный голос, такого я не встречал